# How to grant schema permissions in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I created a new schema in Microsoft SQL Server and created new tables under the new schema (`dev.cc_table`). The problem is that I can't load data into those tables because I get the error message below.

If I change the schema (`dbo.cc_table`) I have no problems loading data.

> An OLE DB record is available.
>
> Source:
>   "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult: 0x80004005
>
> Description:
>   Could not allocate a new page for database 'Development' because of insufficient disk space in filegroup 'PRIMARY

Comment: Your disk runs out of space

Comment: That doesn't sounds like a problem related to the schema, and sounds like you've run out of disc space; as the error suggests.

Comment: I supposed, there is a disk problem, but why when in the same server, same database I just use another schema, I don`t receive any error of disk space? I only receive the disk problem with the new created schema.

Comment: SQL doesn't allocate space row by row, it allocates in big chunks and fills in until it's almost out of space, then allocates another big chunk. You probably still have room in a previously allocated chunk in dbo.cc_table but dev.cc_table would need a new chunk. Try freeing up disk space first (or checking *where* SQL is trying to put that table, it might be in a different filegroup or partition or something) and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Find out where `filegroup 'PRIMARY'` is being stored.  It is possible that your DB is on more-than-one drive (or filegroup).  It could also be a permissions issue. Again, look at permissions for the drive/folder/file where that filegroup is stored.